# Is it possible to reference a caption outside of the figure?

Tags: floats, captions

For my thesis research I want to be able to reference a caption I've made elsewhere in the text so that I can have a page of all my captions separate from the figures themselves.  My figure layout is essentially as follows:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics{./Figures/DummyFigure.png}
\caption[Short Caption]{This is the caption I want to reference elsewhere.}
\label{fig:DummyFigure}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I'm confused. Doesn't `\listoffigures` gives the list that you are looking for?

Comment: I already have a list of figures at the beginning of my document.  I was looking for something I could reference at the beginning of my figures.  Is it possible to have multiple lists of figures throughout the document?

Comment: @Guest12345: Possible, but not easy to achieve, I assume

Answer (score 2):

If you use [`nameref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nameref), you can reference a figure caption elsewhere in your document:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nameref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption[Short Caption]{This is the caption I want to reference elsewhere.}
  \label{fig:DummyFigure}
\end{figure}

\nameref{fig:DummyFigure}

\end{document}
```

You can also use `\listoffigures` to provide a list of figure captions. Moreover, `\listoffigures` can be used at the end of the document if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding `\listoffigures` destroys the lof file after reading it.  However, you can create a fake list of figures anywhere before then.  Just put the real `\listoffigures` last.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fakelof}%
{\bgroup
  \section*{\listfigurename}%
  \parskip=\z@\@plus\p@\relax 
  \InputIfFileExists{\jobname.lof}{}{}%
\egroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption[Short Caption]{This is the caption I want to reference elsewhere.}
\end{figure}

\fakelof

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

[image: double lof]